# django-admin dbshell raises django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: django

I know this question has been asked before, but none of them worked for me so far, so I'm going to give it a chance here.

I'm trying to use MySQL as my database in django, but when I modify the settings.py and run the command:

```
  django-admin dbshell
```

I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES,
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment
variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure()
before accessing settings.
```

What I did:
- I'm running windows 10.

- using pipenv, I create fresh virtual environment.
- install django.
- start new project.
- edit the settings.py
- in the settings.py I change the DATABASES to the following:

  ```
  DATABASES = {
    'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
       'NAME': 'test_db',
       'USER': 'root',
       'PASSWORD': '****',
       'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
       'PORT': '3306',
      }
  }
  ```
- also pip installed mysqlclient

Weird thing is that when I make migrations, new tables are created, which means that DB works. why doesn't the command

```
   django-admin dbshell
```

work?

Comment: I've never run a Django project on Windows and I also don't know if it's related to Windows but have you try to define the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE on your path? Try this: export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings

Answer (score 2):

based on django docs, manage.py does same thing as django-admin, and also adds settings to the sys path, therefore manage.py should be used instead of django-admin

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/